# enzyme test not changing input value and submitting form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test the simple form below. I was able to easily test it with `react-testing-library`, but I want to demo the same test with `enzyme`.

#### Code

```js
<form
  onSubmit={event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleSubmit(firstName);
    this.setState({
      firstName: ""
    });
  }}
>
  <label htmlFor="first-name">First Name:</label>
  <input
    id="first-name"
    value={firstName}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
  />
  <button disabled={!firstName} className="primary" type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

So I wrote the `enzyme` test to change the `input` value then click the `submit` `button`.

#### Test

```js
test("should submit form when the submit button is pressed", () => {
  const handleSubmitMock = jest.fn();
  const names = [];
  const wrapper = mount(
    <Input handleSubmit={handleSubmitMock} names={names} />
  );
  const input = wrapper.find("#first-name");
  const button = wrapper.find("button.primary");

  input.simulate("change", { target: { value: "Bill" } });
  console.log(input.debug()); // input value unchanged 
  console.log(button.debug()); // button still disabled ‍♂️
  button.simulate("click");

  expect(handleSubmitMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

However, my `console.log`'s are showing that input is not changing which means the `button` is still `disabled` so it can not be clicked. Therefore, the `expect` fails because the `handleSubmitMock` function is never called since the `form` is never submitted.

Here is a [CodeSandbxox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-satoshi-9h3ur) with the same code to mess around with.

Answer (score 0):

The simulated `click` call does not properly propagate the `submit` event in the form, so you explicitly have to simulate the `submit` event to trigger it. In order for the form to submit, you need to change `button.simulate('click')` to `button.simulate('submit')`.